# Struggling to get buildozer to work (xubuntu), python 3.8, seems like it miss some dependencies but im not sure

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

well I smh killed by virtual box and I don't remember how I got my first one to work, I installed kivi and buildozer based on kivy.org docs. It dies in the middle of building though, no matter what I try to compile logs are always the same.

```
[INFO]:    -> running make -j 1 -C /home/herbal/Desk...(and 119 more)
           working: make: Leaving directory '/home/herbal/Des...(and 121 more) Exception in thread background thread for pid 14999:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 
 
  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j 1 -C /home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build
 
  STDOUT:
make: Entering directory '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/Makefile.pre.in', needed by 'Makefile.pre'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
 
 
  STDERR:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/hostpython3/__init__.py", line 116, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.make, '-j', str(cpu_count()), '-C', build_dir)
  File "/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 925, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 849, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/herbal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 
 
  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j 1 -C /home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build
 
  STDOUT:
make: Entering directory '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/Makefile.pre.in', needed by 'Makefile.pre'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
 
 
  STDERR:
 
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=conganew --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/herbal/Desktop/snake/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/herbal-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/731,unix/herbal-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/731'
#     WINDOWID = '60817411'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'xfce-'
#     CLUTTER_BACKEND = 'x11'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     LC_NAME = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'xubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '816'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/herbal/Desktop/snake#2'
#     LOGNAME = 'herbal'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'xubuntu'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'gtk2'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/herbal/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/herbal'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     HOME = '/home/herbal'
#     LC_PAPER = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'XFCE'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6001'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING = '0'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'herbal'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c1'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share'
#     PATH = '/home/herbal/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/herbal/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'xubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/home/herbal/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/herbal/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/herbal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/herbal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

here is the log
I tried both installing from GitHub and via pip, I also tried compiling simpler scripts, I also certain I got it to work before my virtual box died with same exact script.

Comment: i also did change the filename to avoid commenting out something with # char

Comment: I don't think kivy is supported with python 3.8. You can't use later than python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the `requirements`:

```
python3,
kivy==2.0.0rc3,
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,
sdl2_ttf==2.0.15
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)